# How can I change one value in style attribute with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a `div` defined with a style attribute:

```
<div id="div1" style="width:600;height:600;border:solid 1px"></div>
```

How can I change the height of the `div` with JavaScript?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeHeight(height)
{
   document.getElementById("div1").style.height = height + "px";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Judging by his example code he is using the dojo framework.  Changing height in dojo would be done with something similiar to the following:

```
dojo.style("div1", "height", 300);
```

http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/dojo/1.2/dojo.style

Comment: +1 for recognizing that the OP may want to keep using his framework.

Answer (score 5):

```
document.getElementById("div1").style.height = height + "px";
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it might look with jQuery:

```
<div id="div1" style="width:600;height:600;border:solid 1px"></div>
<a href="#">Change height to 300</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a').click(function() {
            $('#div1').css('height', '400px');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var d = document.getElementById("div1");
d.style.height = "300px";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your comment with:

node.style.height = height;

Oh, not sure if just passing 300 to your function will make it work, perhaps you'll have to pass "300px" like suggested in the other posts...

Answer (score -1):

In dojo, you would do it like this:

```
dojo.style("div1", "height", "300px");
```

Having the units on the height is important, as [mentioned in the docs](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.2/dojo.style).